# Spring version update

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have some spring components in my project:

spring framework version `5.0.5.RELEASE`
spring boot version `2.0.1.RELEASE`
spring-boot-starter-security version `2.0.1.RELEASE`

I want to upgrade spring-boot-starter-security up to version `2.7.8`, but after that project doesn't start.
Is there something like a table which contains information about these versions compatibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spring boot version` and any `spring-boot-starter-*` dependencies should all share the same version number. You shouldn't be updating any spring-boot-starter packages to be newer than the version of Spring Boot you are using. You generally would only declare the Spring Boot version number in your [Gradle](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/)/[Maven](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/) files, and have it automatically include the same version of the spring-boot-starter packages.

On top of that, each Spring Boot version is built on a specific version of Spring, and that's really the only version of Spring that that version of Spring Boot is guaranteed to be compatible with.

So I suggest looking at the [Spring Boot releases page](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/releases) to determine which version of Spring Boot you want to upgrade to, that includes the versions of Spring and Spring Security you want to use.